# How do you change the turtle's pen color from a value in a list?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have a list of numbers that the turtle draws, but I want the pen color to change based upon the value of the number in the list.

```
colors = ["red", "orange", "green", "cyan", "blue", "purple", "magenta", "pink"]

digits = map(int,str(5))

for number in digits:
    *code to change pen color to value of "index(number)" (in this case purple)*
    t.right(number*10)
```

Just using 5 as an example, is there a way to change the color based on the value of an element in the list?

I'm a bit new to Python, so thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change a turtle's color by accessing it's `.color` method, if it's only the pen color you want to change, you can replace `.color` with `.pencolor`:

```
colors = ["red", "orange", "green", "cyan", "blue", "purple", "magenta", "pink"]

for number in range(5):
    t.color(colors[number])
    t.right(number*10)
```

Or better yet, use `enumerate`:

```
colors = ["red", "orange", "green", "cyan", "blue", "purple", "magenta", "pink"]
for number, color in enumerate(colors):
    t.color(color)
    t.right(number*10)
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for! Thank you!